# Android : Does accessing view in nested layout takes time?

Tags: java, android

I have used same layout many times in the rood layout.Now I am accessing view in nested layout like following. Does it time long time. Is there any better solution.

```
 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fragment_forcast).findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView).
                findViewById(R.id.liner_layout).findViewById(R.id.forcas_layout_1).findViewById(R.id.day_field)
```

Updated: Here is my method:

```
private void populateForcastView(){
    TextView tv;
    View rootView=(View)findViewById(R.id.fragment_forcast).findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView).
            findViewById(R.id.liner_layout);

    for(int forcastFragmentIndex=1; forcastFragmentIndex<=3; forcastFragmentIndex++){
        int forcastFragmentId=getResources().getIdentifier("forcast_layout_" + forcastFragmentIndex, "id", getPackageName());
        tv=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(forcastFragmentId).findViewById(R.id.day_field);
        tv.setText("Sunday");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it now. I posted the correct approach in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the Butterknife library.

https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Answer (score 1):

Just findView by its ID, no need to nest IDs

```
 TextView tv=findViewById(R.id.day_field)
```

Comment: so now you may try to use butterknife library for view binding

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. My approach was wrong.

```
    private void populateForcastView(){
    TextView tv;
    for(int forcastFragmentIndex=1; forcastFragmentIndex<=3; forcastFragmentIndex++){
        int forecastFragmentId=getResources().getIdentifier("forcast_layout_" + forcastFragmentIndex, "id", getPackageName());
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(forecastFragmentId).findViewById(R.id.day_field);
        tv.setText("Sunday");
    }
}
```